# Upload S3 Object with Object Permissions

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, permissions, aws-sdk, .net-4.6

I a using the .Net AWSSDK. I am trying to upload an object with permissions. In the console you can set permissions on an object by object basis and I can't for the life of me work out how to do it in C#.

I want an uploaded object to have Oped/Download permissions for everybody. So far I have the following:

```
try
{
    var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(REGION));

    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    var key = path "/" + fileName;

    fileTransferUtility.Upload(filePath, existingBucketName, key);

    // Set open permissions for file with key
}
catch (AmazonS3Exception s3Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s3Exception.Message, s3Exception.InnerException);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this form](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3TransferTransferUtilityUploadTransferUtilityUploadRequest.html) of the `Upload` function:

```
public virtual void Upload(
         TransferUtilityUploadRequest request
)
```

The `TransferUtilityUploadRequest` contains a `CannedACL` property that can specify [various different values](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3S3CannedACL.html) such as:

- Private
- PublicRead
- PublicReadWrite
- AuthenticatedRead